# How do I include boost/beast/core.hpp in my bitbake recipe? I used DEPENDS = "boost" which works for many boost libraries, but not beast

Tags: yocto, bitbake, boost-beast

I am working on a bitbake/yocto project that requires boost/beast/core.hpp. In my .bb recipe file, as the title mentions, I tried 
`DEPENDS = "boost"`
which successfully adds one other boost library that I need (boost/algorithm/string.hpp), but it does not include boost/beast/core.hpp.

The boost/beast library is installed in /usr/local.

I've tried

`DEPENDS = "boost boost/beast/core"`

and

`DEPENDS = "boost boost-beast-core`

Neither of which works.

I would really appreciate If anyone can show me how to include boost/beast/core.hpp.

Comment: which release are you on ? and which version of boost is being built. with latest master I see this file is part of `boost-dev` ./boost-dev/usr/include/boost/beast/core.hpp so infact adding `DEPENDS += "boost"` in your recipe should have solved it.

Comment: When I run ```bitbake -e virtual/kernel | grep "^PV"```, it says ```PV="4.14.35+gitAUTOINC+118adc53e8"``` 


I'm not sure how to find out which version of boost bitbake is using, but I'm quite certain that it's an older version that doesn't include beast.


Is there a way to update the boost library? Where does the DEPENDS variable search for libraries?

Comment: you can do bitbake -e boost | grep "^PV" to find the version. The boost recipe is in core layer `./meta/recipes-support/boost/boost_1.69.0.bb` on master, you can backport this version back if you are on older release

Comment: My bitbake had boost version 1.64 which did not include the beast library. I changed the recipe to boost 1.69 and it fixed everything. I really appreciate your help.